# Meaning of ADX Cache utilization more than 100%

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

We see Cache utilization dashboard for an ADX cluster on Azure portal, but at times I have noticed that this utilization shows up to be more than 100%. I am trying to understand how to interpret it. Say , for example , if cache utilization shows up as 250% , does it mean that 100% of memory cache is utilized and then beyond that 150% disk cache is being utilized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-metrics#supported-azure-data-explorer-metrics) for the Cache Utilization metric:

> [this is the] Percentage of allocated cache resources currently in use by the cluster.
>
> Cache is the size of SSD allocated for user activity according to the defined cache policy.
>
> An average cache utilization of 80% or less is a sustainable state for a cluster.
>
> If the average cache utilization is above 80%, the cluster should be scaled up to a storage optimized pricing tier or scaled out to more instances. Alternatively, adapt the cache policy (fewer days in cache).
>
> If cache utilization is over 100%, the size of data to be cached, according to the caching policy, is larger that the total size of cache on the cluster.

Comment: so lets say we have Optimized Autoscale turned on for an ADX cluster (with upper limit specified as 100 lets say) and cache utilization is more than 100% while autoscale is not scaling up all the way to 100  -- that is self contradictory right? Because if cache utilization is more than 80% and if there is a room to increase number of nodes , optimized autoscale should definitely scale it up right? So is there any scenario under which optimized autoscale is not increasing number of nodes to the highest limit despite cache utilization being more than 100%?

Comment: there are at least 2 explanations - 1) optimized auto scale runs periodically, and it may have not kicked in yet since your recent increase in cache utilization; 2) there's a capacity issue in your region, which prevents new nodes being added to the cluster. if you're seeing unexpected behavior, i would recommend you open a support ticket for your resource, using the Azure portal.

Comment: when ingestion utilization > 100% , there is no enough SSD storage on a cluster for the amount of cache specified -- so when it says ingestion utilization as 300% , t means all (100%) of SSD is already used up and on top of that we have 200% more SSD requirement (we have so much data to store in cache that if we had 200% more SSD it would have been all used up perfectly) ,but now since all our 100% cache is used up , how is the rest of the 200% data getting stored? Is it stored as disk cache? So part of disk is also used as cache?-- how is that different than normal data residing on disk then?

Comment: It sounds like you are under the impression that the cache is mostly memory based and not SSD based. It's actually the opposite. See the quote from the docs I've included in my initial reply. I'd also recommend you go over the technical whitepaper - it will help you understand the internals of the technology better: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/resources/azure-data-explorer/

Comment: Ok got it , but then where does data reside if it can't be loaded to SSD because SSD is less than the amount of data specified in cache policy? I think it will just stay on disk (cold storage) and be fetched from there which will be obviously slow -- so when we see cache utilization very high like 300% etc it only means that only 33% (one third) of the data could be loaded to SSD and the rest of the 66% (two third) data simply be referenced from disk. Just trying to verify this basic assumption.

Comment: I have the same question, but the paper does not seem to answer that, nor it addressed in the documentation. It is understood that >100% cache utilization means the amount of data to cache is larger than the amount allocated for cache, but it is not clear how exactly this situation is managed by the engine (e.g. it keeps the most recent data that fits in, or the choice is random, etc.), hence not clear the impact of running the cluster in such a state.

Comment: The cache applies an LRU eviction policy if utilization exceeds 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Utilization > 100% means that there's not enough room in the (SSD) cache to hold all the data that the policy indicates should be cached. If auto-scale is enabled then the cluster will be scaled-out as a result.

The cache applies an LRU eviction policy, so that even when utilization exceeds 100% query performance will be as good as possible (though, of course, if queries constantly reference data more than what the cache can hold some performance degradation will be observed.)